# Add/get methods for lists of objects from different classes

Tags: java

I need to create in java Hotel class that stores some rooms, as well as Room class that stores the number of beds in a room and a Bed class that stores the size of a bed(i.e. single or double). The problems occurred during debugging stating that my add/get methods don`t work properly.

Comment: maybe you could be more specific? what does not work well? make an example

Comment: Post a [mcve] and describe your problem in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code of `Room` is wrong. Basically, when you get or add something, you are creating a new room. Use the `this` qualifier to reference to the current room.

```
public int getBedNumber(int i){
    return this.beds.get(i).getNumber();
 }
 public List<Bed> getList() {
     return this.beds;
 }
 public void add(Bed beds) 
 {
        this.beds.add(beds);
 }
```

Comment: Could you please mark my answer as correct? Kind regards.